# MongoDB Query for Time Series data

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a find query to retrieve data only for first hour i.e. hourly : "1" in the following events document. Following is the output from db.events.find().pretty().

In real scenario, I would be finding based on id and hour.

```
{
        "_id" : "08062017/cpu",
        "metadata" : {
                "host" : "localhost",
                "metric" : "cpu"
        },
        "hourly" : {
                "0" : {
                        "total" : 234,
                        "used" : 123
                },
                "1" : {
                        "total" : 234,
                        "used" : 123
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Simply project it. `db.events.find({},{ "hourly.1": 1})`. This is pretty inherent to why you would use this type of structure.

Comment: It works. Thank you.

Comment: How can achieve the same with Spring Mongo @Query